# "The system cannot execute the specified program" on perl --x -S pp.bat -o "myapp.exe" myapp.pl

Tags: windows, perl

Today when I run pp.bat to compile perl programs, I get "The system cannot execute the specified program". The last time I ran pp.bat to compile one of my apps was on April 7 (12 days ago) and it ran fine. I've tried it on 2 of my apps in a standard cmd window and with elevated privs.

I disabled the Windows firewall (public, private, domain) with no effect. I don't have any anti-virus running besides whatever comes built-in to Windows 10. I looked for any blocked settings in properties for Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe and pp.bat but don't see anything. I checked gpedit User Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Don't run specified Windows applications but this wasn't configured (and setting this to Disabled didn't make a difference).

This is on Windows 10 21H2 x64 (in a qemu/kvm virtual machine). I see the following Windows updates that have been installed since April 7th:

> Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1
> Redistributable Package KB2538243
>
> 2022-04 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H2 for x64-based
> Systems KB5012599
>
> 2022-04 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows
> 10 Version 21H2 for x64 KB5012117
>
> Security Update for Microsoft Excel 2013 KB5002175 32-bit Edition

Would you suggest I uninstall KB5012599?

Comment: I would suggest installing anti-virus and deleting pp.bat.

Comment: I agree on installing anti-virus, but pp.bat is the only way I know to compile perl programs into Windows executables, at least without paying for Active Perl or something.

Comment: Actually, the error shows up not on pp.bat but when it runs the command `perl -x -S pp.bat  -o "myapp.exe" myapp.pl` even though there is no problem running `perl -e "print 'Hello World'"` or `perl -v`.

Comment: I uninstalled _2022-04 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H2 for x64-based Systems KB5012599_ but that didn't help- getting the same error. So now I have no ideas and internet searchs didn't provide any useful hints.

Comment: @TLP IT's surely [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp)

Comment: I'm installing PAR::Packer, and Windows Defender [flagged some files as trojans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYDHw.png). (Probably every executable created by pp during testing.) It's probably a false positive, but I have no way to know. It's probably what happened to you too.

Comment: @ikegami Why not make a proper answer?

Comment: @ed., No idea how to resolve it

Comment: @ikegami Fair enough!